# React router activeClassName doesnt set active class for child routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

```
<ul className="right hide-on-med-and-down">
  <li><IndexLink to="/" activeClassName="active">ABOUT</IndexLink></li>
  <li><Link to="blog" activeClassName="active">BLOG</Link></li>
  <li><Link to="discover" activeClassName="active">DISCOVER</Link></li>
  <li><Link to="contact" activeClassName="active">CONTACT</Link></li>
 </ul>
```

this is how my navigation looks like, and when i navigate to /blog, Blog is active. but when i navigate to /blog/my-blog-post, the active class disappears, is there a way to make /blog/my-blog-post set the active class on my blog list item?

Answer (score 2):

```
<Route path="blog" component={Blog}>
  <Route path=":slug" component={Blog}></Route>
</Route>
```

I just had to declare my routes as above and it worked!
This link was helpful: `https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/issues/1684`

Comment: Isn't it true that `:slug` is no longer a routeParam when nested?